# posting image from iphone app to restful WCF

Tags: iphone, .net, ios, wcf

I need to post image from ios app to .net 4 restful WCF service. Can someone help with following codes together (as a working package),

on .NET side: Interface code, Service code (implemenation) and web.config XML.
on IOS side: the posing to the wcf part.

although there seem to be several sources online about how to achieve this, after long time messing with it, still can't get it going.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the server side: take the input as a `Stream` - that way you can receive arbitrary data (including images). More information in this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2008/04/17/wcf-raw-programming-model-receiving-arbitrary-data.aspx). For the client side: take a look at the [NSURLRequest](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class - if you search for examples, you'll find many, including here from StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Just send the image as byte array to the wcf service and store it as blob in SQL server if you need to store.

Comment: though json? not a good solution since I get 400 error on big files since json is getting too large.

Comment: You can always increase json message size in wcf. I can't understand why bytearray could be a bad solution. Another solution could be you can upload the file from ios device to some locationa and from service side you can access the file using URL.

Comment: tried to increase message size, via the 
maxReceivedMessageSize attribute on webHttpBinding and

<system.web>
      <customErrors mode="Off" />
 <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2000000000" />
  </system.web>

and still 400 error on large files.

Comment: It should be maxreceivedmessagesize or something similar